# .NET AppUpdater Component Not Downloading Updates?

Tags: .net, auto-update

I am planning on using the .NET AppUpdater component in one of our company applications, but to test it first of all I created a tiny test application (I followed there documentation here: http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx).

My problem is this...

I have followed the documentation to the letter, setup Directory Browsing on the server with IIS, checked all the URLS with my browser and they all point to the right places (and I can view the list of files on the server), changed the Manifest file to point to the version 2.0.0.0 files on the server, the Assembly version of the app is set to 1.0.0.0 etc.

I have done various debugging on the app, and can confirm that the AppUpdater.CheckForUpdates method returns TRUE. So that suggests it is downloading the UpdateVersion.xml file and realizing there is a new version available - but it never downloads and installs the update...

What it DOES do however, is download the UpdateVersion.xml file and put it in the local 1.0.0.0 folder. It also creates an AppUpdater.xml log file which has a load of garbage, amongst which there is this:

```
<_UpdateFailureEncoutered>false</_UpdateFailureEncoutered>
<_UpdateFailureCount>0</_UpdateFailureCount>
```

Which seems to indicate nothing went wrong... I've tried all of the things suggested in the Debugging section at the bottom of their guide, but nothing works... I'm at a loss, any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was WebDAV was not enabled in IIS. Though this opens up a whole new can of worms with regards to security implications using this AppUpdater.

Comment: Kinda late, but have you abandoned AppUpdater component for the auto update functionality? I'm looking for an auto update mechanism and this is the first I tried and it's pretty simple and free.